# How to quickly add a large list of value to the corresponding python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file with the following format (example), the report_date is currently empty:

```
| ids | disease_code | report_date |
| --- | ------------ | ----------- |
| 10  |    I202      |             |
| 11  |    I232      |             |
| 11  |    I242      |             |
```

I generated a list of tuples from a data source like the following:

```
[(10, ['I202'], 2021-10-22), (11, ['I232', 'I242'], 2021-11-22), (11, ['I232', 'I242'], 2021-11-12),.....]
```

The above order is patient_id, disease_code and the reported_date (The dates are in order corresponding to the disease), for a patient who has more than one disease, the reported date was unfortunately separated into two tuples. Now I want to fill the report_date column by matching the first two values of the tuple with the current csv, like this:

```
| ids | disease_code | report_date |
| --- | ------------ | ----------- |
| 10  |    I202      | 2021-10-22  |
| 11  |    I232      | 2021-11-22  |
| 11  |    I242      | 2021-11-12  |
```

I tried to use a nested loop but it seems like it will take 480 hours to complete. I believe there is a more simple answer but I could not figure it out. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can create a dataframe with your data. You'll see that the column `"disease_code"` contains a list of values, just as you mentioned:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(10, ['I202'], "2021-10-22"), (11, ['I232', 'I242'], "2021-11-22"), (11, ['I232', 'I242'], "2021-11-12")],
    columns=["ids", "disease_code", "report_date"],
)
>> df["report_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["report_date"])
>> df
   ids  disease_code report_date
0   10        [I202]  2021-10-22
1   11  [I232, I242]  2021-11-22
2   11  [I232, I242]  2021-11-12
```

Now you need to separate the values in the `"disease_code"` column by repeating the values in the other columns... [`pd.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) does exactly that. This method transforms values in a list-like column to multiple rows:

```
>> df.explode(["disease_code"])  # Explode the "disease_code" column
   ids disease_code report_date
0   10         I202  2021-10-22
1   11         I232  2021-11-22
1   11         I242  2021-11-22
2   11         I232  2021-11-12
2   11         I242  2021-11-12
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, if I want to only keep 1988 for I232 and 1998 for I242, and remove all the other rows generated by explode, what should i do?

Comment: You mean to select certain rows (as in an additional operation on the result)? Or is that because the output is not the one you expect?

Comment: Yeah, the problem with the original data set is that they have a date for every single disease code but this list made the disease code into a list which is not supposed to be, the [I232, I242] are supposed to be two lines of row which correspond to the report_date respectively.

Comment: I guess I will need to figure out a different way to manipulate the original data... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For new DataFrame use list comprehension:

```
L = [(10, ['I202'], '2021-10-22'), 
     (11, ['I232', 'I242'], '2021-11-22'),
     (11, ['I232', 'I242'], '2021-11-12')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(a, x, c) for a, b, c in L for x in b], 
                   columns=["ids", "disease_code", "report_date"])
print (df1)
   ids disease_code report_date
0   10         I202  2021-10-22
1   11         I232  2021-11-22
2   11         I242  2021-11-22
3   11         I232  2021-11-12
4   11         I242  2021-11-12
```

Then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to original DataFrame `df`, but because there are duplicates in `ids, disease_code` columns first remove them:

```
print (df)
   ids disease_code  report_date
0   10         I202          NaN
1   11         I232          NaN
2   11         I242          NaN

print (df1.drop_duplicates(['ids','disease_code']))
   ids disease_code report_date
0   10         I202  2021-10-22
1   11         I232  2021-11-22
2   11         I242  2021-11-22

df = (df.drop('report_date', axis=1)
        .merge(df1.drop_duplicates(['ids','disease_code']), 
               on=['ids','disease_code']))
print (df)
   ids disease_code report_date
0   10         I202  2021-10-22
1   11         I232  2021-11-22
2   11         I242  2021-11-22
```